# SQL query to get the order of procedures based on their dependent procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query, dependencies, procedure-definition

i have this query to get all sp's and depending(nested) sp's on those sp's. I need to create all these procedures on another database . Any idea how to get them in the correct order.

```
select distinct  procs.NAME AS ProcedureName ,OBJDEP.NAME as DEP_ProcedureName_NAME
FROM    sysdepends
        INNER JOIN sys.objects OBJ ON sysdepends.ID = OBJ.OBJECT_ID
        INNER JOIN sys.objects OBJDEP ON sysdepends.DEPID = OBJDEP.OBJECT_ID
        inner join   sys.procedures procs  on sysdepends.id = procs.object_id
        where OBJDEP.type='P' AND OBJ.type='P'
```

Comment: You are assuming the dependency info in the source database is correct. You could make your life easier by not worrying about creating procs in dependency order and just execute `sp_refreshmodule` for each proc afterwards to fix dependency meta-data. Also, use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` instead of the deprecated `sysdepends` view.

Comment: Or even better IMO, is use some sort of migration tool instead of coding your own migration. This can get messy fast. There are plenty of options out there already.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial answer is:
Backup your database
Restore it
TRUNCATE, DELETE, and/or DROP whatever you don't want.

The simplistic answer is:
Don't try get them in the correct order; script them all as "CREATE OR ALTER" and simply run the entire set repeatedly until you get the same errors twice in a row (i.e. you're no longer reducing the # of errors each run).

This also allows you to avoid issues caused by the dependency tree being incorrect (which I've seen before), circular dependencies (A calls B, and B calls A, possibly inside IF statements), and so on.